# "I would often tell you."

Tags: punctuation, quotations

Can you have a sentence like

> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____, I would often tell you.

and the part that's left out isn't in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the answer is, 'no'.

To use the verb 'tell' without quotation marks, you require an infinitive or a conjunction such as 'that'. This creates *reported/indirect speech*. Here are some examples:

*He would often tell me that he was going to die.*

*He would often tell me to be careful crossing the road.*

If you were to rewrite these using direct speech, they would become:

*"I am going to die," he would often tell me.*

*"Be careful crossing the road," he would often tell me.*

To remove the quotation marks then, you would have to begin the sentences with the infinitive or the adverb, which is very uncomfortable:

*That he was going to die, he would often tell me.*

*To be careful crossing the road, he would often tell me.*

I would say that neither of these are recommended constructions.

We may begin sentences with these clauses, but only if they are treated as nouns:

*That he was going to die was very clear to all who studied him* - where the first phrase is a fact or a piece of knowledge, not a quote.

*To be careful crossing the road is something he would always advise.* - where the first phrase is the *something*, an action treated as a noun.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is a stretch, but if you allow for sardonic usage:

> **She:** "You don't often tell me that you love me."
>
> **He:** "*If you often asked me*, I would often tell you."

Comment: Why the italics?